# Inaccurate badge progress for Refiner

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress, edit-and-answer-badges

I've been working on the *Refiner* badge.  In the past 24 to 36 hours I've answered four questions (and my answers received upvotes, giving each a positive score) and I also edited these question within 12 hours of posting the answer (usually a few minutes).

However, my *Refiner* score in the *progress* indicator in my profile hasn't ticked upward.  I'm wondering why not?

Comment: Caching probably. The badge counts are updated periodically, not instantly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  What's the longest caching could take?

Comment: Also note that tag edits do not count towards the badge; 3 of your 4 question edits were only touching the tags.

Comment: I'd say a day, with the script running once every 24 hours or so.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know, thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The numbers are not updated in real time, they are cached. Wait a day and the number will go up eventually.

Note that only *one* of your edits over on Chemistry counts towards the badge; edits that only change the tags of the question are not eligible.